# display text in a horizontal line , using ng-repeat and bootstrap

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to display each word in a new line. (i can't combined the words, think of hangman game) where words are displayed as blanks

```
    <body ng-init="models = [['H','a','p','p','y'],['X','m','a','s']]">
 <div ng-repeat="m in models">
     <div ng-repeat="movie in m track by $index">
              <span class="control-label1">{{movie}}</span>
     </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

but the get output displayed in vertical manner.

I want it to be displayed as

```
H a p p y
X m a s
```

(with space in between)

http://jsfiddle.net/hr1383/uveyfLz1/

How could i achieve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use span element directly instead of div :)

```
<html ng-app>
   <body ng-init="models = [['H','a','p','p','y'],['X','m','a','s']]">
       <div ng-repeat="m in models">
          <span class="control-label1" ng-repeat="movie in m track by $index">{{movie}} </span>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

It's all about css' display property. Div's "block" by default, and span is "inline". It means, that div takes minimal height which is needed to display its content, and as much width as it can and breaks new line. Span takes minimal height as well as width and doesn't break new line.